If public key is for encryption and private key for decryption, how do you digitally sign using private key?
So many online docs state the same thing that "public key is for encryption and private key for decryption" and "use public key for verifying signatures and private key for creating signatures" , won't you need encrypting ability for digital signatures?
If using RSA, is it the case that either key can be used for encrypting or decrypting , and the other will simply do the inverse of it? If not then how do private key that is stated everywhere is for decrypting, and not encrypting be used for digital signatures?

Wrong QA site, try this and possibly this if you require signature generation. There will probably be more like those on our crypto site.
